# GetFileInfo resulting in First-chance exception

Tags: c#

I have a try/catch block where I use a GetFileInfo to get the size of a specific file. I'm getting an exception shown in the output window of debugger (although the program still continues its run without reacting to the exception in any way).

The error message I get:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

My question here is twofold:

1. Why does the error occur / what can I do to avoid it?
2. Why does the exception show up in the output despite try/catch? Is this because an external dll throws it?

Code:

```
try
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    return fileInfo.Length;
}
catch
{
}
return 0;
```

The above code is in a method that is called and the filePath is `c:\test\test.txt` and the file exists at that location.

Comment: 1. please show the code that sets `filePath`... smells like you forgot to escape the "\"s ;) 2. this is the perfectly fine behaviour of the debuggers output window... you might always be interested in exceptions that occur, no matter if you catch them or not, right?

Comment: Want to post it as answer? (it was exactly that :)  tnx).  only thing open would then be the 2nd question if the error shows up because its from an external dll that throws it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It smells a lot like you forgot to escape the `\`s in your path ;-)
2. As it is always interesting to see exceptions happening in your program, this is indeed the perfectly regular behaviour of the debuggers output window.

Comment: have to admit before that one occuranceI didn't notice that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In VS you can choose *Debug* -> *Exceptions* and turn off automatic breaking when a particular type of exception is thrown.